# Git diff on topic branch, excluding merge commits that happened in the meantime?

Tags: git, diff, git-merge, aggregation

Let's say I have the following situation:

```
    B---D---F---G topic
   /       /
--A---C---E master
```

For code review purposes, I would like to pull out a diff from commit A to commit G, but not including commits E and C which happened on the master branch, and also not including commit F which is a merge commit.

In other words, I would like to generate a diff that contains changes from F to G and aggregate those changes with changes from A to D.

In other-other words, I want the review diff to contain only my changes from the topic branch, not including a bunch of code from master that happened in the meantime.

Is this possible? If git cannot handle such "diff aggregations", I would be very thankful if someone can provide some pointers as to how some external command can do that (so that I can try writing a bash script which would do the trick).

Comment: What about checkout the file in A and G commit separately and make a vim diff???

Comment: I need the diff for all files, not a single file. Also, I think what you're suggesting will also include changes introduced by the merge commit.

Comment: The triple dot seems like it helped for me this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17618008/4200039

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care what's in the "context" part of the diffs, then `git diff master..topic` will give you what you want.  Any changes introduced in `C` and `E` are considered part of the  "base" of the diff, so the changes from `master` will be there in the context, but only the actual changes made in your topic branch will be marked with `+` or `-` as changes.  That's usually what people want for code reviews.

If instead you want to act like the merge never happened, you will have to rebase it out:

```
git rebase --onto A master
```

Comment: Thanks Karl, `git diff master..topic` did the trick. It turns out that I had to merge master into topic before running the diff script.

Answer (score 10):

**The answer from Karl is misleading:**

`git diff` never works on proper ranges (i.e. multiple commits), only between *two* commits!

The range syntax has special meaning for `git diff`.

`git diff E..G` is always equal to `git diff E G` (and
`git diff E...G` is equal to `git diff E G` in this case, because E is the merge-base between the two).

`git diff master...topic` is what you want in this *and in the general case*: it shows you all changes of the topic branch, comparing it to the last merge-base (i.e. contrasting it to master when it was merged the last time, ignoring all later changes in master which are not in your topic branch anyway).

*Note:* unfortunately (by coincidence?) the effect of `x..y` in `git log`, etc. is best represented by `x...y` in `git diff` and vice versa!

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer. From the manual: "git diff A...B" is equivalent to "git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B".

Answer (score 1):

What about:

1. git checkout topic
2. git checkout -b temp
3. git revert F
4. git diff A

Afterwards you can happily remove the temp branch.