# git diff showing only commits that revision/branch A is ahead of revision/branch B

Tags: git

Sometimes I have the following problem:

1. Add some commits in a feature branch.
2. Update master from upstream.
3. Want to see the diff between the feature branch and master, but `git diff master` shows all of the things that have been added/removed in master, when I really only want to see the commits that the feature branch is ahead of master, not the ones that it's behind.

Is there a way to do this without having to merge master into the feature branch?

Comment: This question doesn't make it clear about whether you want to see ***commits*** that `feature` has that `master` doesn't have, or whether you only want to see ***the diff*** of changes made in the feature branch that haven't been made in `master`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Git, show all commits that are in one branch, but not the other(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710894/using-git-show-all-commits-that-are-in-one-branch-but-not-the-others)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I think the right answer is triple dot

```
git diff master...feature
```

That shows only new changes on feature with respect to master. See also: [git diff - show only what's new on the remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670265/git-diff-show-only-whats-new-on-the-remote/17617690)

Comment: It also works if your on the feature branch and you do `git diff master...` omitting the feature branch name :)

Answer (score 38):

I usually go for

```
git log -p feature-branch --not master
```

But if you want a diff, you're looking for

```
git diff <common-ancestor> master
```

where `<common-ancestor>` is a common ancestor of your feature branch and master that you want to compare to. You can use `merge-base` to find that for you.

```
git diff `git merge-base feature-branch master` feature-branch
```

Comment: Won't this show the commits on Master after the branch point and not the changes on the feature-branch?

Comment: Using `git log master --not <commit-sha-id>` without the `-p` I obtained the commits without the diff.

Comment: In case if you want to have whole diff for commits which are in the branch, but not in the `master` you can also use `git diff master^ feature-branch` or even just `git diff master^` - this recipe will work even for Windows, where cmd.exe has no backticks.

Answer (score 36):

Your question is a little unclear because I'm not sure if you want to see a diff/patch of the changes between `master` and `feature`, or you just want to see which branches contain which commits that the other branch doesn't have.

Assuming that you just want to see what commits are in your `feature` branch that don't exist in `master` (i.e. which commits in `feature` are "ahead" of `master`), then you can do

```
$ git log --oneline --graph master..feature
```

If you want to see how both `master` and `feature` have diverged, you can use this command:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --first-parent \
--decorate --left-right master...feature
> 5bef654 (feature) A ...
> f7c65ea B ...
> fc66245 C ...
> 7435fc0 D ...
< bf68204 (master) X ...
< 0c10ed1 Y ...
< 27bb774 Z ...
```

The above output shows commits in `master` that are not in `feature` with `<` in front of them (since you used `master...feature` with master on the left `<` side of the command), while commits in `feature` that aren't in master are marked with `>` since you used `feature` on the right side of `master...feature`.  The triple dots `...` in this form are important, don't leave them out.

You can learn more about specifying [Commit Range from the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges).

Comment: `$ git log --oneline --graph master..feature` this works perfect

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your feature branch is off of the master branch, and you want to see the differences between what you have committed on the feature branch and what the master branch looked like when you branched from it.

```
A----B----C
 \
  D----E----F
```

In that case you can use use the `git diff` command with the corresponding hashes of the commits.  So for a feature branch that branched at point A and has subsequently committed D, E, and F, you can do this:

```
git diff <hash of commit F> <hash of commit A>
```

You can use `git merge-base feature master` to see the hash of point A to use above, and `git log` to see the hash for your most recent commit, F, on the feature branch.  Or to do it all on one line use this command:

```
git diff feature `git merge-base feature master`
```

Comment: Note that you can do this in one line by using `git merge-base`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer, but a one liner that works most of the time for my needs.

`git difftool -d master..`