# Review changes from multiple commits

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm using `git-svn` to work with an SVN repository.  One of the things I want to be able to do is review changes with `git diff` and all its nice options.

Sometimes, "work-in-progress" changes are committed to SVN, and I want to wait until the work is finished before reviewing.  I'm wondering if there's an invocation of `git diff` that will let me see all these related changes, without any intervening commits.

Visually, I have:

```
* e00 yet more irrelevant stuff
* a04 finish work
* a03 more wip
* d00 irrelevant stuff
* a02 more wip
* c00 other irrelevant stuff
* a01 more wip
* a00 start wip
* b00 state of tree before wip starts
```

I want to be able to see what the cumulative effect of the `a**` commits are on top of `b00`, without `c00`, `d00`, or `e00`.  `git diff b00 a04` has irrelevant changes.  `git show a0{0,1,2,3,4}` gives too much intermediate noise.

I'd like to be able to do this without creating a throw-away branch, as my current approach does.

Similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78339/extract-relevant-changes-for-code-review) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488956/git-diff-on-topic-branch-excluding-merge-commits-that-happened-in-the-meantime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really do need a temporary place to aggregate the changes, so your current method is fine.  But you can use an unnamed branch (a "detached HEAD") to make it automatically go away:

```
$ git checkout --detach b00
```

(or without `--detach`, `a00^`: either way, get current with `b00` but also detach `HEAD`), then exactly as before:

```
$ git cherry-pick a0{0,1,2,3,4}
$ git diff master...
$ git checkout master
```

and you're done: there's no branch to delete.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've come up with so far is this:

```
git checkout -b review-temp a00^
git cherry-pick a0{0,1,2,3,4}
git diff master...
git checkout master
git branch -D review-temp
```

(I've posted this as an answer so I can accept it if no other alternatives arise.)