# generating diff between between two branches, after a partial review

Tags: git, git-diff

Let's say I have this situation in git:

```
  B---D---F---H---J---K--->topic
 /       /       /
A---C---E---G---I--->master
```

After getting as far as commit F, I submit the topic branch for review. The reviewer makes some suggestions, and the world moves on, so another merge is done. As answered here [Git diff on topic branch, excluding merge commits that happened in the meantime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488956/git-diff-on-topic-branch-excluding-merge-commits-that-happened-in-the-meantime) the way to generate the diff from A to F simply `git diff master..topic`. Now however, revisions B and D have already been reviewed, and I would like to exclude them from a new diff for review. `git diff E..topic` includes G and I however.

How do I get a diff of H, J and K, excluding things pulled in through G and I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

torek's suggestion (to do multiple reviews) is a possibility, but has the unfortunate side effect of meaning that code that was say in need of improvement after `F` and fixed in `H` must be reviewed twice: once in its sub-par state, and once when it has been finished. The nice thing about `git diff master..topic` was that it squashed these, and just gave the final difference between the branches.

What I did to solve the problem was create a branch from `F`, merge `master` into there, and then do a diff between my new temporary branch and the `topic` branch. That way all changes to `master` were glossed over, and only the changes to the `topic` branch since the previous review point are used.

Answer (score 1):

Except for some special cases involving merge diffs (when you can use `--combined`), commit diffs are always pair-wise.  This changes the way `x..y` gets interpreted.  Instead of this meaning "all revs reachable from `y` that are not reachable from `x`", it means "compare rev `x` with rev `y`".

(It's worth noting here that the answer in the linked question glosses over the fact that `x..y` is interpreted differently in `git diff` than in other git commands.)

When you ask for `E..topic`, git resolves `topic` to a specific commit—in this case `K`—and then compares the tree in `E` to the tree in `K`.  That's why you see changes from `G` and `I`, because those changes were brought in through `J` via the merge.

You could compare `F` and `K`, but this will still show the changes in `G` and `I`, because again, those changes are actually in `J`.

There is, in fact, only one way to ignore what happened in `J` while keeping `F` and `H` intact like that, and that is to build up a tree that either skips it, or reverts it.  For instance, starting at `H`, you could add a patch based on the diff between `J` and `K`:

```
                K'        <-- HEAD[detached]
               /
  B---D---F---H---J---K   <-- topic
 /       /       /
A---C---E---G---I         <-- master
```

(to do this, `git checkout topic~2` to get detached at commit `H`, then `git cherry-pick topic` to add, to your now detached `HEAD`, the changes made to go from `J` to `K`).

Now you can compare the tree in commit `E` with the tree in `HEAD` (at commit `K'`):

```
git diff E HEAD   # or   git diff E..HEAD   or   git diff E..
```

But that's not, in general, what people want to review.  In fact, since you will almost certainly subsequently abandon rev `K'` entirely (generating it only for review purposes), they will be reviewing a version of code that is never used!

This is *why* the accepted answer to the linked question is to just `git diff master..topic`—which means exactly the same thing as `git diff master topic`, and in this case compares the tree for `I` with the tree for `K`.  You are proposing to submit, on branch `topic`, a tree that looks like `K`.  That's the code that will be in `topic`.  It has some difference to the code that is in rev `I` in `master`.  The difference it has *to `I`* is the sum of the changes in `F`, `H`, `K`, and any shim work that was done to make `J` fit in.  It *does* have the changes made in `G` (and of course those in `I` itself) but those are not changes *to* `I`, those are merely changes incorporated *in* `I`.

A more thorough way to review the code is to present four diffs for review:

1. `E` vs `F`
2. `F` vs `H`
3. `H` vs `J` (perhaps a combined diff, `H`-and-`I` vs `J`)
4. `J` vs `K`

The first diff tells your reviewers that, if they accept it, it's going to be possible to check out a tree that looks like `F` (which is certainly true, just `git checkout F`).  The second diff tells your reviewers that, having `F` in their repos, it's going to be possible to check out `H` (if they accept that), etc.  Obviously four reviews are harder than one, which is why people accept short-cuts like comparing `I` vs `K`.